# `std::views::split` on MSVC

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, std-ranges, compiler-specific

I want to split a string by a token with `std::views::split`, and for each retrieved substring invoke the `std::from_chars` function.
Here is an MRE (https://godbolt.org/z/1K71qo9s4) that compiles successfully on GCC but fails to compile on MSVC:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <charconv>
 
 
int main()
{
    std::string source{"10%15%20%35"};
    for ( auto i : source | std::views::split('%') )
    {
        int x;
        std::from_chars( i.begin().base(), i.end().base(), x );
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
}
```

What strange is that according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view#Notes), the behavior of `std::views::split` was changed in [P2210R2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2210r2.html#class-template-split_view_iterator_-range.split2.iterator), providing `base()` function which effect is

> Equivalent to `return cur_`

Then, according to [compiler support page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), the `P2210R2` is supported in MSVC since 19.31, so the example should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this were working how you think it does, `i.begin().base()` should be a `std::string::iterator`, which has to be `const char*` (or at least convertible to a `const char*`) to pass to `std::from_chars`.

Looks like libstdc++ also doesn't implement this properly either, and `i.begin()` is returning a `std::string::iterator` instead of a `std::ranges::views::split_view<std::string>::iterator`. It just so happens that libstdc++'s `std::string::iterator` has a function called `base()` that returns a pointer.

You have to get a `const char*` pointer anyways, which you can do with [`std::to_address`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address):

```cpp
    std::from_chars( std::to_address(i.begin()), std::to_address(i.end()), x );
```

Or something like:

```cpp
    std::from_chars( std::ranges::data(i), std::ranges::data(i) + std::ranges::size(i), x );

// Or, since span is constructible from ranges

for (std::span<const char> i : source | std::views::split('%')) {
    std::from_chars( i.data(), i.data() + i.size(), x );
```

Answer (score 4):

`source | std::views::split('%')` produces a nested range whose `value_type` is `subrange`, so in your example, the type of `i` is *actually* a `subrange` containing two iterators of `source`, which is `string::iterator`.

Thus, `i.begin()` calls `subrange::begin()`, which returns the underlying `string::iterator` object. For MSVC-STL, `string::iterator` does not provide a `base()` member, because this is an *implementation-defined* type, which only requires to conform to [[container.requirements]](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements)
specification, which does not include providing a `base()`. This is why your code fails.

However, you can use `std::to_address` to get the raw pointer

```
std::from_chars(std::to_address(i.begin()), std::to_address(i.end()), x);
```

---

> What strange is that according to cppreference, the behavior of
> `std::views::split` was changed in P2210R2, providing `base()` function
> which effect is

You are misunderstanding the usage. `split_view::iterator` *does* provide a `base()`, so `(source | std::views::split('%')).begin().base()` still works.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers here seem to be overcomplicating things. In:

```cpp
for ( auto i : source | std::views::split('%') )
```

`i` is a `ranges::subrange<string::iterator>`. That's a contiguous, sized range. That means that `subrange` provides `data()` and `size()` for you, so this works:

```cpp
for ( auto i : source | std::views::split('%') )
{
    int x;
    std::from_chars( i.data(), i.data() + i.size(), x );
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}
```

You don't need to first convert this to a `span` and you definitely don't need `std::to_address`.

Comment: Great catch. When I first saw the OP I was blinded by the [P2584](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2584r0.pdf)'s Tony table that popped into my mind.